Is $E[Y \mid X_1,X_2]=E[Y \mid X_1,X_2,X_2^2, X_1X_2]$ always true?
Is $E[Y \mid X_1,X_2]=E[Y\mid X_1,X_2,X_2^2, X_1X_2]$ a correct statement? If so, why does this hold? If not, under what conditions does this hold?
Initially I think they are the same, but when I put them in the context of regression, I started to get confused. In particular, if this is true, when running the regressions, we don't need to include any quadratic terms, like $age^2$ in the wage equation.
Thanks!

Your last sentence is false.

In general, $\mathbb E\left[Y\mid Z_1,Z_2,\dots,Z_k\right]$ is a shortcut for $\mathbb E\left[Y\mid\sigma\left(Z_1,Z_2,\dots,Z_k\right)\right]$, where $\sigma\left(Z_1,Z_2,\dots,Z_k\right)$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the random variables $Z_1,\dots,Z_k$, that is, the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ for which all the random variables $Z_1,\dots,Z_k$ are measurable.
In the context of the question, it suffices to show that $$\sigma\left(X_1,X_2\right)=\sigma\left(X_1,X_2,X_2^2,X_1X_2\right).\tag{*}$$ The inclusion $\subset$ holds by definition (using $\sigma(Z_1)\subset\sigma(Z_1,Z_2)$ repeatedly). For the other, note that $\sigma\left(X_2^2\right)\subset \sigma(X_2)\subset\sigma\left(X_1,X_2\right)$ and
$\sigma\left(X_1X_2\right)\subset \sigma\left(X_1,X_2\right)$ hence
$\sigma\left(X_2^2,X_1X_2\right)\subset \sigma\left(X_1,X_2\right)$ and the inclusion $\supset$ in (*) follows.
Notice that there is nothing specific in the product structure or square: we would get by the same argument that if $f_1,f_2\colon\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ are Borel-measurable, then
$$
\mathbb E\left[Y\mid X_1,X_2,f_1(X_1,X_2),f_2(X_1,X_2)\right]=
\mathbb E\left[Y\mid X_1,X_2\right].
$$

Hi Davide, thanks a lot for the response! What makes me confused is that if  these two are equal, since linear regression is the best linear predictor for $E[Y|X_1,X_2]$, why do we still need to have $X_1^2$ sometimes? Is it because with this inclusion, we obtain some non-linearity as an advanatge?

You are welcome, and by the way, welcome to Math Stack Exchange! I cannot tell without the exact context of the equalities.

@LCV97 : Note that the expectation is a (-n unspecified) function of $X_1$ and $X_2$.  The (independent variables) are $X_1$ and $X_2$, but the value of that function can depend on powers (and other, less elementary functions) of $X_1$ and $X_2$.  So the expectation (notation) exposes the dependence on $X_1$ and $X_2$ while regression tries to extract the details of how the value of that function is calculated from those variables, so can expose nonlinear dependence.

@EricTowers I see. Thanks a lot for the explanation!
